# Using both first row of data and last row of data within a formula e.g match

Tags: excel, vba

I need Excel to identify the first row of data used and the last row of data used.

I want to write a match formula in a cell next to my data and starting with the same row and auto fill/copy till last row.

For example the first row was 30 and the last row was 50.

My formula will be in Cell B30 and it will be =match(E30,$H$30:$H$50,0)
then auto fill B30 until B50

```
Dim alr As Long  (lastrow)  
alr = Range("D50000").End(xlUp).Row


Dim ast As Long (firstrow)
ast = Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row + 2


Dim rng1 As String (austofill range)
rng1 = "B" & ast & ":" & "B" & alr

Range("B" & ast).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[3],RastC8:RalrC8,0)"
ActiveCell.Copy
Range(rng1).PasteSpecial
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate the first and last row vars into the string that represents your formula.

```
Dim alr As Long,  ast As Long

alr = Range("D" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
ast = Range("D1").End(xlDown).Row + 2

range("B" & ast & ":B" & alr).FormulaR1C1 = _
     "=MATCH(RC[3], R" & ast & "C8:R" & alr & "C8, 0)"
```

You can write the entire 'austofill' range of formulas at once.